# Differentiability of a function with a power series representation with a finite radius

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Given $f(x) = S(x)$ for $x \in (-R, R)$, where $S(x)$ denotes a power series, does it imply that $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable given it can be represented as a power series?

For instance $f(x)=\frac{\arctan (\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$ can be represented as a power series $\sum (-1)^n \frac{x^n}{2n+1}$, with a radius $1$. Is that fact enough to proof that $f$ is infinitely differentiable given the radius is not infinite, or does it only proof that $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $(0, 1)$, if so how to proof $f$ is of class $C^{\infty}$ on $(0, \infty)$?

Comment: The power series argument only works inside the radius of convergence. Buy away from it, the function is clearly smooth by the chain and quotient rules.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The derivative still contains $\arctan(\sqrt{x})$ I know this is a smooth function but does it really prove that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: Smooth means $C^{\infty}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yeah I get it, what I mean is the fact that I know it's smooth doesn't prove it yet

Comment: So you're saying you don't know how to prove composition and products (resp. quotients) of $C^{\infty}$ functions is $C^{\infty}$? If that's the case then you have a separate question to deal with. Prove that first. It's a basic and very standard theorem which can be proved using the chain/product rules (and also using induction if you wanna be precise).

Comment: There is a small disconnect between your original question, where the function equals the power series on $(-R, R)$, and the particular application, where $f(x)$ is only defined for $x > 0$. Mind you, it is not a big deal - your intent is understandable. Also (because it is a pet peeve of mine), "proof" is a noun. The verb is "prove".